# cocos2dx OpenGL error 0x0506 when dismissing UIViewController

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x

I've run into very difficult issue. In the `Cocos2d-x` game i'm working upon currently (it's main part is written by another developer i'm just finishing it, and by now it is supposed to work on iOS only so i don't care about all the Android related stuff ) i need to use `UIViewController`. I present it and dismiss in a very usual way:

present:

```
 SDMoreAppsViewController *vc = [[SDMoreAppsViewController new] autorelease];
 [viewController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];// viewController is UIWindow root view controller
```

dismiss:

```
 UIViewController *controller = self.presentingViewController;
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Once the view controller is successfully dismissed i see the message in my console telling me that `opengl error 0x0506` has appeared. This message is printed from methods `swapBuffers` of `EAGLView` and `draw` of `CCSprite`. Along with this message my whole scene becomes unresponsive. Tapping buttons gives no result.

I've tried a lot of things already. I tried pushing my view controller and adding it as a child instead of presenting but it doesn't even shows the view controller (viewWillAppear method doesn't get called), i also tried adding its view as a subview to my app's window but that also brings a lot of different errors.

I'm using cocos2d-x version cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.3.

Did someone solve such a problem before? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

before presentViewController, pause rendering:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();
```

call resume and startAnimation in completion block